# Devise Confirmation Email Not Being Sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable, cloud9

I am developing a Rails app on Cloud9, I am trying to do something pretty simple, which is to get the Devise confirmation emails to work. For some reason, they are not being sent.

I'm using SendGrid for email functionality. I know that SendGrid is working correctly, because I can make a trivial ActionMailer that sends a test email. But for some reason, the Devise confirmation emails are not being sent. I can see that it is making a call on `ActionMailer::Base.mail` method, but the mail is never delivered.

I have no idea how to debug this.

Just to prevent suggestions to check stuff that is already working:

- The user options include `:confirmable`
- I am setting `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`
- I have the following lines in `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`

Code:

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:           '2525',
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  domain:          "sendgrid.com",
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Comment: In trying to debug what was going on, I tried calling `mail` from within the rails console. What I found was that directly calling `ActionMailer::Base.mail` never results in the mail being delivered, but if I call it indirectly through a subclass of `ActionMailer`, it works. Why in the world wouldn't the base class work?

Comment: Why would it work? ActionMailer::Base is made to be subclassed.

Comment: But the subclass doesn't seem to add much functionality:
`class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end`

Comment: Shouldn't the port be an integer compared to a string?

Comment: check the `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` line and set that to true so you can see the errors if any

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that my solution is not the intended solution, but it works (although I'm not sure why).

In the file `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`, I added the following two lines:

1. `ActionMailer::Base.layout 'mailer'`
2. `ActionMailer::Base.default from: "from@example.com"`

These are probably things that should be specified in some configuration file for Devise, but I didn't see any instructions for doing so.

[Edit] It is only line 2 that is important. It doesn't matter that the "from" address is a bogus email address, but if it is missing, the email does not get delivered.